# How to marshal iOS NSDictionary in NativeScript?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nativescript

I am trying to implement one Native library in NativeScript. The native code like this:

```
@implementation ViewController
{
    NSDictionary *mediaInfo;
}

- (void)mediaPickerController:(IQMediaPickerController*)controller didFinishMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info;
{
    NSLog(@"Info: %@",info);//Here you'll get the information about captured or picked assets

    mediaInfo = [info copy];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

So, I am trying like this:

```
public mediaPickerControllerDidFinishMediaWithInfo(controller, info) {

    let mediaInfo = info.copy();
    console.log(mediaInfo);

  }
```

I am getting output like this:

```
{
    IQMediaTypeImage =     (
                {
            IQMediaImage = "<UIImage: 0x608000290090> size {4288, 2848} orientation 0 scale 1.000000";
        }
    );
```

But I can't acccess the information. Anyone can help me please?